# MySQL - Order By 2 columns without Filesort

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to display the latest 'sweepstakes' news entries, but I would like to display the non-expired ones first. I would also like to order them showing the latest entries first.

However, no matter how I write the query or index it, MySQL always wants to use filesort.

```
SELECT F.sid, F.title, F.url, F.description, F.bodytext, F.img, F.url, F.submitted_by, F.category, F.ptime, F.expired,
SUM(if(C.active = 1, 1, 0)) AS commentCount
FROM News AS F
LEFT JOIN news_comments.comments AS C ON F.sid = C.postid
WHERE category = 'sweepstakes' AND F.sid
GROUP BY F.sid
ORDER BY F.expired, F.sid DESC
LIMIT 1, 8

+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                 | key          | key_len | ref                         | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | F     | ref  | category                      | category     | 98      | const                       |  158 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | C     | ref  | get_comments                  | get_comments | 4       | News.F.sid                  |    1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have indexes on category, sid, and expired. The 'expired' column contains 1 for expired, 0 for not expired.

Can this query be rewritten in a different way to avoid filesort?

EDIT: Table Structure

```
News | CREATE TABLE `News` (
`sid` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`url` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(160) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`bodytext` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`img` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`submitted_by` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`category` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`ptime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`expired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
KEY `category` (`category`,`sid`,`expired`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1082 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Order by 2 *rows* or columns?

Comment: Is there a real technical issue with it or you just don't like the "Using filesort" label?

Comment: order by 2 columns - isn't using filesort bad?

Comment: "I have indexes on category, sid, and expired." --- what does it mean? A composite index? Separate indexes?

Comment: "isn't using filesort bad" --- define the "bad" term please? Does the query performance suit your current performance requirements?

Comment: zerkms - I'm not good with tech. terms. I indexed 'category' in phpmyadmin and then edited it and added 'sid' and 'expired' to it.

Comment: @Mayhem: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to show the real schema. Btw, even if you create a "proper" index - your query won't be optimized the way you want - you `GROUP BY` one field, then you sort by another

Comment: The query takes longer to execute when using 'temporary' and 'filesort'.

Comment: "The query takes longer to execute when using 'temporary' and 'filesort'. " --- longer than **what**? How long does it take to run at this moment?

Comment: May I ask why that matters? Query times has nothing to do with my original question. I'm just wondering if my issue can be resolved.

Comment: @Mayhem: it matters because **there is no issue**. You have no idea what those flags mean but want to avoid them. Performance optimization with serious lack of knowledge is just a wasting of time. Anyway, I already told that: 1. it's not possible for this query 2. it makes no sense to optimize something that already works well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: it's `EXPLAIN` execution time (just a scientific guess) :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why it's showing 0.00 in that EXPLAIN - when I run the query in phpmyadmin, it takes about 1.2 seconds. If I remove the ORDER BY F.expired, it takes 0.0004 seconds.

Comment: Just a notification: you still haven't provided a schema for the tables. It's not possible to give a real advice without them

Comment: @zerkms: ah! Too much Postgres I guess. Postgres reports the actual query execution time in the explain output.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE gives this error : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: isn't for `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` only?

Comment: @Mayhem: if you have any issues with syntax - please consult with documentation first before you write here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-table.html If you cannot deal with a trivial `SHOW CREATE` sql - then may be it's too early to deal with performance optimization?

Comment: What `AND F.sid` condition is for?

Comment: I've never had the need to use that command before - guess I can blame that on phpmyadmin. I've edited my post with the table structure.

Comment: To be completely honest, I have no idea. I think I left that in by accident when testing different query ideas.

Comment: Just a side note: in a *big* systems if you need to be able to fetch number of comments quickly and often - you would just store them in a `News` table and retrieve without `GROUP BY` and joins. And maintain via triggers or some queue.